# rails ransack checkbox filter with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ransack

I am using the ransack gem in my rails app. I have been able to implement a search feature with ajax in my views. I want to do something similar with checkbox filters. So essentially when a user clicks on the checkbox, it should display results immediately without the user having to click the submit button. Currently, the filter checkbox works fine with the submit button but I have no idea what jquery code i need to use to make it filter with ajax. This is my index.html with the ransack filter

```
<% new_roles = [] %>
<%= search_form_for @search, :class => 'filters_click' do |f| %>
  <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <% new_roles << job.role %>
<% end %>

  <% new_roles.uniq.each do |new| %>
    <%= check_box_tag('q[role_eq_any][]', new) %>
    <%= new %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
<div class="jobs"><%= render 'jobs' %></div>
```

This is my index.js

```
$(".jobs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("jobs")) %>");
```

I would like to know what jquery code to write in my js so I can use Ajax to provide filter results when the user clicks on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the Ajax request when the checkbox is clicked, like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  alert ("Checkbox " + this.id + " clicked.");

  $.ajax({
    url: "your-query-url",
    data: $(".filters_click").serialize();
  });
});
```

But I think the easiest way to do it, it's to add `remote: true` to the form, and then just make the submit of the form with jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(".filters_click").submit();
});
```